# MariaDB ERROR: ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Quando eu rodo esse código no MariaDB, ele me dá este erro ao tentar criar a tabela brinquedo:

> ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column
>   size is 767 bytes.

Eu não sei como corrigir, o MariaDB já veio instalado no meu sistema o Parrot Sec (Uma distro baseada em Debian). Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoria (
  categoria_id INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoria_nome VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (categoria_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX categoria_nome_UNIQUE (categoria_nome ASC));


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brinquedo (
  brinquedo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  brinquedo_descricao VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_imagem_url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_preco DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_detalhes VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_categoria_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_marca VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (brinquedo_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX brinquedo_imagem_url_UNIQUE (brinquedo_imagem_url ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_brinquedo_categoria
    FOREIGN KEY (brinquedo_categoria_id)
    REFERENCES categoria (categoria_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Campo 'longos' como varchar não são bons candidatos para indices. Para ser um indice ele não deve ultrapassar determinado valor (consultar na documentação o número exado de caractes) para ser útil. O problema parece ser `brinquedo_imagem_url`. Se não me engano no MySQL o limite é 120. Sugestão remova o indice dessa coluna ou se possível diminua o número de caracteres.

Comment: Fiz isso, e agora ele da erro na criação da foreign:

brinquedo_marca VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (brinquedo_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_brinquedo_categoria
    FOREIGN KEY (brinquedo_categoria_id)
    REFERENCES categoria (categoria_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `brinquedos`.`brinquedo` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você usa `utf8mb4`, cada caractere de um campo `CHAR` ou `VARCHAR` reserva 4 bytes, portanto, seus 200 caracteres podem precisar de até 800 bytes.

Se realmente precisa desse índice, ou precisa diminuir um pouco o campo...

```
 brinquedo_imagem_url VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL
 -- 180 x 4 = 720 --
```

...ou então pode manter os 200, mas definir um *charset* diferente para ele:

```
  brinquedo_imagem_url VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET binary ...
```

Ficando algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brinquedo (
  brinquedo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  brinquedo_descricao VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_imagem_url VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET binary NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_preco DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_detalhes VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_categoria_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_marca VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT ...
  ...
```

Notar que para decidir o melhor charset você tem que analisar pra que mais ele é usado além do `UNIQUE`.

Segue a listagem dos charsets do MariaDB e do MySQL:

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/supported-character-sets-and-collations/

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: beleza. tou limpando meus comentários aqui, menos o link do manual. Ao abrir a nova pergunta, lembre de mencionar qual engine vc está usando no MariaDB (e se lembrar, qual usava no MySQL)

Comment: Valeu bacco, era isso mesmo!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, e que a pessoa da outra pergunta, a do UNSIGNED estava atenta. Era um detalhezinho chato de perceber. Foi um tiro bem certeiro :) - Pena que alguém deu -1 aqui também, mas faz parte. O importante é que resolveu pra você e outros tambem aprovaram.

Comment: Pois é, no MySQL funcionava sem o unsigned, acho que ele assumia como default!

Comment: Beleza. Qq coisa, deixe um coment ou pergunta.

Comment: Esse SQL faz parte de um trabalho que eu queria relembrar, tem coisa que nem lembro mais de onde tirei mas enfim, funcionou! Veleu mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Troque o `INT(11)` e o `INT(10)` por `SERIAL`. `SERIAL` é um alias("apelido") para `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`

O problema no seu código é a declaração do tipo da chave primária, portanto isso resolve. Lembre-se de não duplicar o os outros atributos que o `SERIAL` já preenche.

[Fonte para consulta](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment/)

Comment: Fiz as alteraçõe e o erro permanece o mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was to put the lines below in my maria db configuration file (*in my case /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/server.cnf*):

```
[mysqld]

innodb_large_prefix=on
innodb_file_format=Barracuda

innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).