# SQLSTATE 42000: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Depois que criei o projeto com o comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel-scout` fui fazer as seguintes alterações no arquivo **.env**

```
DB_DATABASE=course
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Em seguida criei a base de dados com o mesmo nome de `course`

Em seguida efetuei o comando **php artisan migrate** dentro do projeto, e gerou esse erro;

```
PS C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-scout> php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)
  )



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes


PS C:\Users\wladimir\Desktop\php\laravel-scout>
```

1. Alguém pode me explicar o que significa o Erro?
2. Alguém poderia me explicar como corrigir o erro?

Obs: eu estou sando **Xampp**, é um aplicativo que instala PHP e Mysql.

Comment: Coloca o código da criação da tabela ou classe do laravel que cria essa tabela.

Comment: [ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174331/91)

Comment: Queria entender o motivo do downvote na pergunta e na minha resposta, isso é um problema do Migrations e não diretamente do MySql, afinal quem *"gera"* a estrutura é o Framework, ela não foi feita *manualmente*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Também já passei por isso, a melhor solução que achei foi alterar o **AppServiceProvider**, com isso não preciso ficar ajustando os campos sempre que criar uma nova *migration*. Segundo a [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations):

> Laravel usa o conjunto de caracteres utf8mb4 por padrão, que inclui
>   suporte para armazenar "emojis" no banco de dados. Se você estiver
>   executando uma versão do MySQL mais antiga do que a versão 5.7.7 ou
>   MariaDB anterior à versão 10.2.2, talvez seja necessário configurar
>   manualmente o comprimento da string padrão gerado pelas migrações para
>   que o MySQL crie índices para elas. Você pode configurar isso chamando
>   o método **Schema::defaultStringLength** no **AppServiceProvider**:

Para resolver isso siga os passos abaixo:

1. Edite o arquivo **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**
2. Adicione o namespace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`
3. Dentro do método **boot** adicione `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

Resultado final do arquivo:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Para mais informações consultar documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations